# why 'intent.getstringextra("key")' is null?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-activity

i am making board for kotlin
but when uploading from firebase storage  android studio said key is `Null`
why `key = intent.getStringExtra("key").toString()` is NULL?
Please give me a solution
here is BoardInsideActivity

```
class BoardInsideActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var key: String
    private val binding: ActivityBoardInsideBinding by lazy {
        ActivityBoardInsideBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    }
    lateinit var datas: BoardModel
    private val Tag = BoardInsideActivity::class.java.simpleName
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        datas = intent.getSerializableExtra("data") as BoardModel
        binding.titlePage.text = datas.title
        binding.contentPage.text = datas.contents
        binding.timePage.text = datas.time

        key = intent.getStringExtra("key").toString()
        Log.d("test", key)
        getImagefromFB(key)

    }
        private fun getImagefromFB(key: String) {

        val storageReference = Firebase.storage.reference.child(key+".png")
        val imageViewFromFB = binding.imagePage


        storageReference.downloadUrl.addOnCompleteListener(OnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                Glide.with(this)
                    .load(task.result)
                    .into(imageViewFromFB)
            } else {
                imageViewFromFB.isVisible = false
                Toast.makeText(this,key,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

        })
    }
}
```

Comment: I am guessing you are navigating this activity from another activity. And you are not sending `key` correctly from there. Check that out, if you can not manage it share your previous activity code with us too.

Comment: Based on the given information no one knows